# Evdev Wheel Emulation by keyboard

Tags: kernel, xorg, drivers, mouse, xinput

I love XInput mouse wheel emulation! Evdev Wheel Emulation can enable on any mouse button by running bellow command (9 is the mouse button that trigger Evdev Wheel Emulation)

```
xinput set-prop $DEVICE_ID "Evdev Wheel Emulation Button" 9
```

I use it for almost 5 years and realy thankful to xorg guys who implement this great feature. Now I want to change the trigger from a mouse button to a keyboard key. Say I want to enable trigger emulation when I hold "H" key and disable when I release magic "H". How can I do that?

#### Tested Solutions That Not Worked

I tried to map a keyboard key to a mouse button 9 but pressing button 9 wont do the tricks. It seems that Evdev wont stimulate by a synthetic mouse button press. I create a script that when a magic "H" key pressed it run `xdotool mousedpown 9` and run `xdotool mouseup 9` on release of the key. I can confirm script do what it supposed to do by changing button from 9 to 1 (aka left click) and see holding "H" on keyboard will hold left click down but no hope on Evdev Emulation

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to create a virtual pointer with uinput module and python. then create a script to emit mouse button in virtual pointer on key press on keyboard.

I wrote a full explanation on my [blog](http://bijan.binaee.com/index.php/2018/10/27/evdev-wheel-emulation-by-keyboard/). If you need more detail you can check it out